# Generate a Menu that Displays Child Pages using wp_list_pages() with the New Menu Functionality in WordPress 3.0?

Tags: menus

Previously, I was able to selectively load child pages for a currently-selected parent page using logic such as:

```
if(  $post->post_parent ) {
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
} else {
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
}

if ($children) { ?>
   <ul id="subnav">
     <?php echo $children; ?>
   </ul>
<?php 
} else {
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a native way to do this using the new register_nav_menus()/wp_nav_menu() functionality. Anyone know how I could patch this together at this point?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Drop down Child menu screenshot]

Comment: This is tough, since wp_nav_menu doesn't relate to page hierarchy (or pages at all, for that matter). I don't know enough about menus to answer this now, but this is a very interesting question.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. What are you trying to accomplish? I see the code but I don't get the context. Got a site that does want? A screenshot?

Comment: He wants to add child items of top level menu items conditionally (i.e. only if that tree structure is active) in the new nav menu api.

Comment: @John P. Bloch - What does *"only if the tree structure is active"* mean? Are we talking Pages only? What about Posts, Categories, Tags, Custom Posts, etc? Does he want to do it on the client via jQuery or in the server? I guess I'd rather not assume and I'd like to hear more about the actual use-case.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel In this particular case, I think we may be talking pages only, but that doesn't matter anyway; the solution will still be the same. I think ZaMoose wants it done server-side.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel John is correct. I want to load child pages (if they exist) for the curent parent page and then output an unordered list of said children. Essentially this allows for a contextual submenu for pages.

Comment: @ZaMoose: Sorry for being so dense. What do you mean "*load child pages?"* Does this mean the same? *"I want to output an unordered list of child pages if a page has child pages."* And where do you want to output them? As part of a drop down menu or somewhere else on the page? I know it's perfectly clear to you and evidently to John but I'm just missing exactly what you want.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel:
This image should illustrate what I'm going for.

http://skitch.com/zamoose/d12rt/about-us-delta-sigma-theta-sorority-inc-south-jersey-alumnae-chapter

Comment: @ZaMoose - Perfect, thanks (Dude, I just love Skitch, don't you? :) I'm going to edit your post to include your screenshot. That said, I see @jessegavin answered you but it doesn't work with BuddyPress? Hmm, that wasn't in your question or I would have let it pass by because I'm not up to speed on BuddyPress yet.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: Yeah, I've broken the BP portion out into a separate question. I'm going to mark @jessegavin's answer as authoritative.

Comment: Cool. I'm going to remove the *"BuddyPress"* I added from the title.

Comment: ...And yes, Skitch is quite the asset for annotating screenshots. *grin*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a Widget named Page Sub Navigation (clever I know) that is working for me.

If you install this, you can just drag the widget to one of your widget areas and ***BAM*** it works.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Page Sub Navigation
Plugin URI: http://codegavin.com/wordpress/sub-nav
Description: Displays a list of child pages for the current page
Author: Jesse Gavin
Version: 1
Author URI: http://codegavin.com
*/

function createPageSubMenu()
{
  if (is_page()) {
    global $wp_query;

    if( empty($wp_query->post->post_parent) ) {
      $parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
    } else {
      $parent = $wp_query->post->post_parent;
    }

    $title = get_the_title($parent);

    if(wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=0" )) {
      echo "<div id='submenu'>";
      echo "<h3><span>$title</span></h3>";
      echo "<ul>";
      wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=1" );
      echo "</ul>";
      echo "</div>";
    }
  }
}


function widget_pageSubNav($args) {
  extract($args);
  echo $before_widget;
  createPageSubMenu();
  echo $after_widget;
}

function pageSubMenu_init()
{
  wp_register_sidebar_widget("cg-sidebar-widget", __('Page Sub Navigation'), 'widget_pageSubNav');
}
add_action("plugins_loaded", "pageSubMenu_init");
?>
```

Or if you just want the juicy parts...

```
if (is_page()) {
  global $wp_query;

  if( empty($wp_query->post->post_parent) ) {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
  } else {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->post_parent;
  }

  if(wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=0" )) {
    wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=1" );
  }
}
```

### UPDATE

I found another plugin that does essentially the same thing (and maybe does it better, I don't know).  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subpages-widget/

Comment: This is SO, so close to what I need. The only problem is that it misbehaves when BuddyPress is active.

Answer (score 2):

you could do a css hack to do this (2 ways that I would try)

1 this is the easiest way I can think of do make the css display the items in the subnavigation.

```
.current-menu-ancestor ul {display:inline;}
.current-menu-parent ul (display:inline;}
```

2 assuming that your theme supports body classes you could create a nav menu for each "sub nav", and set them to display beneath the main navigation - then edit your stylesheet to only show the subnav div's using something like this:

```
.child-menu-about, .child-menu-leadership {display:none;}
body.page-id-YOUR_ABOUT_PAGE_ID .child-menu-about {display:inline;}
body.category-YOUR-CATEGORY-SLUG  .child-menu-leadership {display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="site-nav children-link">
                <?php       

                    if(  $post->post_parent ) 
                    {
                      $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                      $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
                    }

                    if ($children) { ?>
                       <ul>

                            <?php echo $children; ?>

                       </ul>

                    <?php 
                        } else {
                        }
                ?>
        </nav>
```

### CSS

```
/*children-links links*/

.children-link 
{       

        background-color: #1a5957;
        color:#FFF;
        font-size: 100%;

}

.children-link li
{
    margin: 10px;   


}

.children-link ul li a:link,
.children-link ul li a:visited 
{
        padding: 15px 17px;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid #1a5957;

}
.children-link ul li a:hover 
{
        background-color: #1a5957;
        color:#FFF;
        font-weight: bold;

}
.children-link .current_page_item a:link,
.children-link .current_page_item a:visited
{

    background-color: #1a5957;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
1 this is the  php display .

[image]
2 this is the  css display .

Comment: Posting answers as code screenshots is the worst possible way - please reedit your answer. A few words of explanation wouldn't hurt also.