# Is it still not possible to show separate submenu with "Custom Menu"?

Tags: menus

Well, the title says it all. Is it still not possible to show separate submenu with the "WP Custom Menu"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display a portion/ branch of the menu tree using wp_nav_menu()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/display-a-portion-branch-of-the-menu-tree-using-wp-nav-menu)

Comment: Well, the title may say it all but _"all"_ isn't enough for me to understand what you are asking. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using custom walker object, Try this solution:

http://helperclass.blogspot.com/2011/11/creating-separate-sub-menu-in-wordpress.html