# Put a wp_nav_menu inside another one

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I've got two wp_nav_menu's defined - main and sub.  The backend menu editor lets me add pages or categories or custom links to my menu, and I can place them under existing pages/categories/links.

However, I want to add my sub pages to the sub menu, and then be able to add that sub menu as a whole item to my main menu.

That way, if I change up what's in my sub menu, I don't also have to go change my main menu too, see what I mean.  Nice and DRY.  Useful if I have my submenu in multiple places (like as a drop down from the main menu, plus on a detail page in the sidebar.)

Is this possible?  Is there a plug in or custom function?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps accomplish this via a [custom walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class), but I suggest you try a single menu containing submenus and display the submenus in other contexts by outputting just that branch of the main menu. see [Display a portion/ branch of the menu tree using wp_nav_menu()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/display-a-portion-branch-of-the-menu-tree-using-wp-nav-menu), specifically [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/2809/4771).

Comment: Hmmm, interesting approach, I didn't think of that, I guess it can work, but it's still rather complex, especially for end users.  I was hoping to find a way to add an "add menu" metabox with a dropdown of other menues.  If I don't get a closer answer I'll credit your answer as a possible alternate solution.