# How to get IDs for objects in menu branch?

Tags: menus, templates, page-template

Is it possible to print content of all menu items, when displaying menu (or branch of menu as in question about [displaying menu branches](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/display-a-portion-branch-of-the-menu-tree-using-wp-nav-menu)) ?

[image]

Once I click on `About Us` I wish for new page to display content of all it's children links.

So basically I am looking for a way to get IDs of those posts/pages and use them inside my WP Query.

Comment: Looking at your edit - so which one is it: displaying content when rendering menu or just retrieving IDs? Please clarify and if latter we need to adjust title again. :)

Comment: you think wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items() might help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am lazy to write supporting logic from scratch so I am reusing functions from linked answer on branches:

```
/**
 * Retrieve IDs of posts in branch of menu.
 *
 * @param mixed  $menu
 * @param string $branch_title
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/display-a-portion-branch-of-the-menu-tree-using-wp-nav-menu
 *
 * @return array
 */
function get_post_ids_from_menu_branch( $menu, $branch_title ) {

    $menu_object = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu );
    $menu_items  = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_object->term_id );
    $items       = submenu_limit( $menu_items, (object) array( 'submenu' => $branch_title ) );
    $items       = wp_list_filter( $items, array( 'object' => 'post' ) );
    $ids         = wp_list_pluck( $items, 'object_id' );

    return $ids;
}

// example
var_dump( get_post_ids_from_menu_branch( 'Test menu', 'Level 1' ) );
```

Comment: WOW! That's some really good news. Never heard of `wp_list_filter` & `wp_list_pluck` but this is just what I was after. Many thanks! You saved the day ;)