# wp_nav_menu show 1 item only

Tags: menus, array

I was reading Wordpress documentation and also trying to find some clear example of how to do this but I couldn't, sorry if this is posted elsewhere but I did my best trying to find an answer before posting.

My question is simple, if I use the wp_nav_menu function of wp, what should I do in the array or any other place to show one specific element and it's childs.

So for example, I have a menu Home, About, Services. My question would be how to show only Services for example with it's childs.

Is that even possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching some more I found this great answer, they key was to use a custom walker.

[Display a portion/ branch of the menu tree using wp_nav_menu()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/display-a-portion-branch-of-the-menu-tree-using-wp-nav-menu/2809#2809)

Best.

Comment: Hi @Jaypee. Great that you found a solution! You can select your own answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you only want to display one item from a menu of many items? You can create additional menus by registering them in your functions.php file and then associating then in the Appearance -> Menus area of the WP-Admin.

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/06/01/goodbye-headaches-hello-menus

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the thing I'm looking for is to not have to create new menus (that will be like a part only of the main menu) indeed. That's why I'm looking to only show a single item of the main menu. Get my point? Thanks!

Comment: The answer sounds stupidly simple. Will work for me.