# How to display conditional-content if wp_nav_menu( $args ) retruns something

Tags: php, menus, conditional-content, sub-menu

I have a sidebar that displays child links of the current page (using this solotuin by https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/2809/27414) which works perfectly.

If there is child links to be displayed in the side bar I would like to give it a heading such as "Also is this section".

I have tried the following which didn't work:

```
if (wp_nav_menu( $args )){
    echo "Also in this section";
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `has_nav_menu` to check if a location has been assigned a menu or not

```
<?php
if ( has_nav_menu( $location ) ) {
     echo "Also in this section";
}
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu

For more advanced checks you'll need to do a call to [`wp_get_nav_menu_items`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) and process the items it returns to see if any of them are children.

Here's an example outputting a menu that shows how to use its output:

```
// Get the nav menu based on $menu_name (same as 'theme_location' or 'menu' arg to wp_nav_menu)
// This code based on wp_nav_menu's code to get Menu ID from menu slug

$menu_name = 'custom_menu_slug';

if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );

    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

    $menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '">';

    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
        $title = $menu_item->title;
        $url = $menu_item->url;
        $menu_list .= '<li><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
    }
    $menu_list .= '</ul>';
} else {
    $menu_list = '<ul><li>Menu "' . $menu_name . '" not defined.</li></ul>';
}
// $menu_list now ready to output
```

A vital thing to note is that a nav menu is made out of nav menu items, **and these menu items are custom post types**. Use the parent child association to determine the depth, just as you would with pages and posts

Comment: Why do you need to use has_nav_menu to check if a location has been assigned a menu or not?

Comment: because that's what the original asker wanted to know, if the location has been assigned show one thing, else show another.