# Custom wp_nav_menu output (displaying all child elements of top menu element in current branch)

Tags: plugins, menus

I would like to create a walker function, or modify somehow current `wp_nav_menus` so it can produce a custom output.
Let's imagine this structure:

```
menu item 1
menu item 2
 submenu item a
 submenu item b
menu item 3
 submenu item c
 submenu item d
 submenu item e
```

The easiest part is to show in one place only main menu items (main menu 1,2,3), and it can be done with wp_nav_menus, so we don't need to code it.

The problematic part is to show in other place submenu items of currently main item...
So if user is on 'menu item 1' page, nothing shows.
If user is on 'menu item 2' page, our "new" custom menu shows:

```
submenu item a
submenu item b
```

Same menu items renders when user is on either of two above pages (menu items).

When user clicks 'menu item 3' and visits its target page, he sees submenu items c,d,e, same as after clicking on any of those submenu items.

If the menu has 3rd level elements (and deeper), custom menu should display all child elements of current most top menu element, beside that top element itself (which will be listed in top part of the site described in first place)

Is there a way of creating such functionality?

The idea is close to:
[Display a portion/branch of menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/display-a-portion-branch-of-the-menu-tree-using-wp-nav-menu)
just it needs to be dynamic and display child elements of current menu branch/all child elements of top menu branch element if they exist.

AFAIK I can't use `get_ancestors`, because it works only with hierarchical taxonomies, and here we are not talking about menu created from post/pages hierarchical structure, but with use of menu editor.

**SOLVED:**
Seems I was able to create correct functions kombining few methods:

```
/**
 * The API function, just a wrap for wp_nav_menu adding filter first and removing after
 */ 
function filtered_nav_menu( $args = array() ) {
    $echo = isset($args['echo']) ? (bool)$args['echo'] : true;
    $args['echo'] = false;
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'gmfnv_filter', 999 );
    $menu = wp_nav_menu( $args );
    remove_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'gmfnv_filter', 999 );
    if ( $echo ) echo $menu;
    else return $menu;
}

/**
 * The filter callback, return the filtered elements
 */
function gmfnv_filter( $items ) {
    $found_top_parent_ID = false;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ( ($item->menu_item_parent == 0 && $item->current_item_ancestor == 1) || ($item->menu_item_parent == 0 && $item->current == 1) ) {
            $found_top_parent_ID = $item->ID;
        }
    }
    $children  = submenu_get_children_ids( $found_top_parent_ID, $items );
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $item->ID, $children ) )
            unset($items[$key]);
    }
    return $items;
}

/**
 * Helper function: return children of an element using wp_filter_object_list
 */
function submenu_get_children_ids( $id, $items ) {
    $ids = wp_filter_object_list( $items, array( 'menu_item_parent' => $id ), 'and', 'ID' );
    foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
        $ids = array_merge( $ids, submenu_get_children_ids( $id, $items ) );
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

What it does - it search for current branch top ancestor by going through each $items element and checking against:

```
($item->menu_item_parent == 0 && $item->current_item_ancestor == 1) || ($item->menu_item_parent == 0 && $item->current == 1)
```

This conditional needs to be 2 part, because top level menu element might also be current one.

If top level $item is found, then function `submenu_get_children_ids` is used to list all its child elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display a portion/ branch of the menu tree using wp_nav_menu()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/display-a-portion-branch-of-the-menu-tree-using-wp-nav-menu)

Comment: Well, almost, just I need it to be dynamic and display children of only current brach (either it is a top menu element as a current page or any to its child elements)

Comment: you can make [this solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/2809/4771) dynamic by just passing the current page's top most ancestor as the submenu argument. see [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) and [`get_ancestors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors).

Comment: I don't think it can be done with use of get_ancestors, as it works only on hierarchical elements, and we are talking about editable menu structure, that don't connect with posts/page hierarchical, or am I wrong?

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just control what is shown / hidden using css and the rich class naming that WP provides for it's menus?

Comment: @cale_b - its the worst case scenario, but I'm searching a way to do it pure html/php based.

Comment: @MarcinBobowski if you tell me which kind of details you miss in the answer, maybe I can edit it adding them.

Comment: @G.M. This is the menu: http://d.pr/i/DAkB, this is the php callout: http://d.pr/i/S3L6, I'm on "Partnerzy" subpage, and the result looks this way: http://d.pr/i/jqRW. It should display: "Partnerzy, Galeria, Projekty" instead of "Strona glowna", "Kontakt".

Comment: @MarcinBobowski I've edited the code, now it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The idea

Instead of create a custom walker I thought was easier filter the items using the filter **`wp_nav_menu_objects`** hook.

This hook is defined in [`/wp-includes/nav-menu-templates.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L318) and whe is fired, it pass to functions hooking into it an array `$sorted_menu_items` that contains all the elements of the menu being printed, if the function alter that array, adding or removing items, the resulting menu will be altered.

### The method

If the filter to `wp_nav_menu_objects` is applyed direclty, **all** menus will be filtered, so I thought was better create **a function that wrap `wp_nav_menu`** adding the filter *before* calling `wp_nav_menu` and remove it *after*: in this way only the wanted menu is filtered.

### The filter workflow

1. Cycle all items passed by `wp_nav_menu_objects` filter hook
2. Create 2 helper arrays: one only of parent ids, one with items like `$itemid => $parentid`
3. While looping items, also check it item url match the current url
4. if url not match return only parent items
5. if url match, using the helper arrays cretaed, return the wanted elements

### The code

The code I wrote for that, make use of 5 functions, so I create a plugin to contains all that, here the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Filtered Nav Menus
 * Author: Giuseppe  Mazzapica
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/118720/
 * Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/35541/
 */

/**
 * The API function, just a wrap for wp_nav_menu adding filter first and removing after
 */ 
function filtered_nav_menu( $args = array() ) {
  $echo = isset($args['echo']) ? (bool)$args['echo'] : true;
  $args['echo'] = false;
  add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'gmfnv_filter', 999 );
  $menu = wp_nav_menu( $args );
  remove_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'gmfnv_filter', 999 );
  if ( $echo ) echo $menu;
  else return $menu;
}

/**
 * The filter callback, return the filtered elements
 */
function gmfnv_filter( $items ) {
  $found = false;
  $parents = $items_tree = $allowed = array();
  $all_items = $items;
  while ( ! empty( $items ) ) {
    $item = array_shift( $items );
    $items_tree[$item->ID] = $item->menu_item_parent;
    if ( (int) $item->menu_item_parent == 0 ) $parents[] = $item->ID;
    if ( isset($item->current) && $item->current ) $found = $item->ID;
  }
  if ( ! $found ) {
    $ids = $parents;
  } else {
    $tree = gmfnv_get_tree( $found, $all_items, $items_tree );
    $ids = array_merge( $parents, $tree );
  }
  foreach ( $all_items as $item ) {
    if ( in_array( $item->ID, $ids ) ) $allowed[] = $item;
  }
  return $allowed;
}


/**
 * Helper function: take the matched element if and the helper array and
 * return the item ancestors by gmfnv_get_parents,
 * and the children of these ancestors returned by gmfnv_get_parents
 * using gmfnv_get_parents
 */
function gmfnv_get_tree( $test, $items, $tree ) {
  $parents = gmfnv_get_parents( $test, $items );
  $parents[] = $test;
  $n = array();
  foreach ( $parents as $parent ) {
    $n = array_merge( $n, gmfnv_get_childrens( $parent, $tree ) );
  }
  return array_unique( $n );
}


/**
 * Helper function: return ancestors of an element using the helper array
 */
function gmfnv_get_parents( $test, $items ) {
  $parents = array();
  foreach( $items as $item ) {
      if (
        (isset($item->current_item_ancestor) && $item->current_item_ancestor)
        || (isset($item->current_item_ancestor) && $item->current_item_ancestor)
      ) $parents[] = $item->ID;
  }
  return $parents;
}


/**
 * Helper function: return children of an element using the helper array
 */
function gmfnv_get_childrens( $test, $tree ) {
  $children = array();
  foreach ( $tree as $child => $parent ) {
    if ( $parent == $test ) $children[] = $child;
  }
  return $children;
}
```

### How To

Create a file containing this plugin put in plugins folder and activate.

When you want filter a menu as required, instead using `wp_nav_menu( $args )` use

```
filtered_nav_menu( $args );
```

### Disclaimer

Code provided *as is*, no warranty, but just quickly tested on PHP 5.4, WP 3.7 with twentytherteen theme active, and no other plugins: it worked in this case.

Comment: Ok, it seems it doesn't work as expected. With simple menu structure: {MainitemA, MainitemB: {subitem1, subitem2, subitem3}} it displays only MainitemA and MainitemB whenever I go.

Comment: Trying debuggind the code I have found, that in gmfnv_filter( $items ), $found is alway false, even when the item $item->menu_item_parent != 0 (there is a parent to the item).

Comment: You are genius. Thanks so much for the help. Ill spend hours on figuring out how this work, but hopefully will get it to the bare bones :). Again, great thanks.

Comment: PS - I strongly suggest posting this solution as a plugin to WP repository :).

Comment: Hmm... Somehow after few days of break code don't work anymore :/. And as I cant seem to understand the code completely - I don't know where the problem lies :(

Comment: Yes, Im going through every step and already when in function gmfnv_filter, there is a $parents array that holds all first level elements - and they should never get back from filter as allowed - just because if current page is top level element - our custom menu should return nothing,
Now $tree seems to collect data correctly (at least when menu has 2 levels) but then is merged back to parents - and that returns original structure as long as menu has 2 levels.

Comment: Now the tricky part happens when we talk about 3 level menu. When active site is a parent of submenus, $tree holds only its child elements. When one of them has another child - item is not listed (perhaps its correct). When second level element is active - than all second and third level elements goes to $tree. Same when third level element is selected.

Comment: The biggest problem that I see now - is that 1rst level elements are shown by our custom menu - and the menu should show nothing when 1rst level element has no child elements, and should show all child elements (hierarchically structured) when it has child elements (it should show children but parent should not be visible).

Comment: No problem.

From analytical point of view script should detect 2 cases:
1. Current item is 1rst (main) level item (menu_item_parent==0) and has child elements - then it should collect all child elements and display their structured code (starting from menu 2 level elements that are children of this top level element)
2. If element is not 1rst level element (menu_item_parent!=0), then it should find its top parent element, and again - collect all child elements of that parent element and print them hierarchically.

Comment: have you been able to find a monute or two?

Comment: @MarcinBobowski I'll have a look in a hour

Comment: Seems I was able to solve it by connecting your method with one pointed in comments to original post. I have edited original message and posted working solution.
Still - without your help I wouldn't have a working solution ;)