# WordPress menu walker - Get parent item text inside end_lvl function

Tags: theme-development, customization, menus, walker, sub-menu

I have a parent menu item which is taxonomy name. I want to add in a mega menu with a featured post from the menu taxonomy in the left of the sub menu.

This code works and shows displays the html correctly, but I'm not sure how to get the parent menu item text (To query the featured post details).

```
public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output .= "$indent</ul></div><div class=\"col-md-8\">Featured Post</div></div>\n";
}
```

How could I get the parent menu item text inside the end_lcl function?

```
public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    // This is the piece I'm missing
    $parent_menu_item_text = ??????;
    $args = array( 'taxonomy' => $parent_menu_item_text );
    // Query the post with the $args etc..
    $output .= "$indent</ul></div><div class=\"col-md-8\">Featured Post</div></div>\n";
}
```

I've seen this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120419/show-top-level-parent-with-submenu-menu-walker) but seems like the the class code has been updated since then (2013)

Comment: you will have to do it in `start_el` the menu item object is not passed to `end_lvl`

Comment: How do I pass it through the start_el?

Comment: the menu item is already being passed in `start_el` as $item

Comment: This is the question, how could it be passed somehow to the end_lvl