# Getting parent object_id of child menu items in WordPress menu

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I am building a menu for a client that grabs custom field data from the top level menu item's pages and adds `data-color` to that menu item. I have that part working no problem.

The issue I'm having is applying that `data-color` from the top level item to the child menu items. Since the child menu items aren't necessarily child posts/pages of the top level pages I can't use `$item->post_parent`.

I'm a little stuck at this point on my next move. Here's the code block so far.

```
function data_attribs_menu( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    // check if ACF exists
    if( class_exists('acf') ) {     
        $page_section = get_field( 'page_section', $item->object_id );
        $parent_page_section = get_field( 'page_section', $item->post_parent );

        if( $args->theme_location == 'header-menu' ) {
            if( $item->menu_item_parent == 0 ) {
                $atts['data-color'] = $page_section;
            } else {
                $atts['data-color'] = $parent_page_section;
            }
        }
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'data_attribs_menu', 10, 3);
```

Is there a way to grab the parent's `object_id` for submenu items?

Here's a video of how the menu is currently interacting.
[image: Current Menu Interaction without Sub Menus Working]

Comment: Does it have to use `data-color`? It might be easier to use WP's built-in classes and build a small JS to the effect of, "if .menu-item-has-children:nth-child(1) or its children are in focus or hovered on, add .blue class to the whole menu" then use the .blue class to apply a partly transparent CSS background color on top of the image.

Comment: in `post_parent` you have the parent of the post selected for this menu item. but you have also `menu_item_parent` which is the identifier of the menu item parent of the current menu item. if the color is associated to the parent post, you need something like `$parentItem = get_post($post->menu_item_parent); $parent_page_section = get_field( 'page_section', $parentItem->object_id);`

Comment: @mmm the `menu_item_parent` part is just testing if they are top level items in the menu. I still need to grab some info from the top level pages though which is where I'm getting hung up.

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 mistakes in my comment.
try rather this code

```
function data_attribs_menu( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    // check if ACF exists
    if( class_exists('acf') ) {     

        $page_section = get_field( 'page_section', $item->object_id );

        if( $args->theme_location == 'header-menu' ) {
            if( $item->menu_item_parent == 0 ) {
                $atts['data-color'] = $page_section;
            } else {
                $parentItem = get_post($item->menu_item_parent);
                $parent_page_section = get_field( 'page_section', $parentItem->_menu_item_object_id);

                $atts['data-color'] = $parent_page_section;
            }
        }

    }

    return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'data_attribs_menu', 10, 3);
```

this code only works when there is 2 levels of menu and according the example in the question, it's what you need.

Comment: Thanks @mmm that works great. Unfortunately I have 3 levels of hierarchy so I'll have to try and modify it for that. If there's a way add `data-color` to the top level `li` that may be the most robust down the road in case the hierarchy changes. Is that even possible? I know how to add classes to the `ul` and `a` but it seems a little more obscure on how to add to the `li`.

Comment: I ended up using a Walker on my menu (based off this [Stack Exchange post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/120419/118926)) to add a data attribute to the parent `li`. @WebElaine got me thinking along this track originally so thank you both for the help.