# Include Custom Post Type Archive in wp_list_pages

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-list-pages

I am wondering how to include a custom post type archive in wp_list_pages.

If there were a page ID, I could simply attach that page to the list using the 'include' argument. I know that there is a 'post_type' argument as well... but that will only list the posts, not the archive, and I need this link to be inserted alongside pages.

Is there any way for me to pull this off? Here is the code I'm using:

```
$parentID    = get_top_parent_id($post->ID);
$parentTitle = get_the_title($parentID);
$parentLink  = get_permalink($parentID);

$args = array(
    'child_of' => $parentID
);

$pages = get_pages($args);

if ($pages) {

    $pageIDs = array();

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $pageIDs[] = $page->ID;
    }

    $args = array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'include' => $parentID . ',' . implode(",", $pageIDs)
    );

    wp_list_pages($args);

}
```

**UPDATE**

Since it seemed like I wasn't going to be able to solve this the way I wanted to, I ended up taking a different approach. I found the question "[Display a portion/ branch of the menu tree using wp_nav_menu()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/display-a-portion-branch-of-the-menu-tree-using-wp-nav-menu)" and Rarst's answer is pretty amazing. Below is my little bit of code for creating the sidebar menu that I needed (I use WPML - hence the ICL_object):

```
<?php
/*
 * PAGE SIDEBAR
 *
*/

$parentID   = get_top_parent_id($post->ID);
$parentLink = get_permalink($parentID);

if ( is_singular( 'custom_post_type_NAME' ) ) {
    $cptParentID = icl_object_id( 77, 'page', false );
    $parentTitle = get_the_title($cptParentID);
} else {
    $parentTitle = get_the_title($parentID);
}

$navArgs = array(
    'menu'    => 51,
    'submenu' => $parentTitle,
    'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
    'container' => false
);

?>

    <article id="news-widget" class="widget postloop list-widget">

        <h5>
            <a href="<?php echo $parentLink; ?>" class="widget-title" title="<?php echo $parentTitle; ?>"><?php echo $parentTitle; ?></a>
        </h5>

        <nav id="secondary-navigation" class="nav-secondary">

            <ul class="pages-navlist">
                <?php wp_nav_menu($navArgs); ?>
            </ul>

        </nav>

    </article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be create a simple list of pages by yourself and then tag on the archives you want.

You can use [get_post_type_archive_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link) to grab the link of any archive you need.

If you could explain more about what it is you need exactly I can knock up some example code for you.

Comment: I would vote up your answer... but I don't have the rep points to allow for it :( Thanks though. I ended up taking a different approach that in the end works a bit better for me, but I could of definitely managed a solid solution with a conditional and the get_post_type_archive_link() - Thanks again!