# wp_nav_menu list children if on parent page but sibling if on sibling page

Tags: menus

For example:

About Page (Parent)

- History
- Mission & Vision
- Location

If I'm on the About Page, I need the wp_nav_menu to show the three children pages. But if I'm on the History page, I need it to show History (with current class), Mission & Vision and Location.

Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Yes there's a way. Please look at the answer to this question. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/display-a-portion-branch-of-the-menu-tree-using-wp-nav-menu/2809#2809

Comment: This will display the children of the parent page. But if I'm on the child page, I want to display the sibling pages.

Comment: In your theme you can check to see if you're in a parent page or child page and then get the ID of the parent page of that child page. Once you have the ID, you can get the Page title and use it to pull the correct menu.