# Generate a Menu that displays all child pages of top level parent

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I used [this answer's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/537/3206) code to generate a widget that displays all subpages of the parent's page:

```
if (is_page()) {
  global $wp_query;

  if( empty($wp_query->post->post_parent) ) {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
  } else {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->post_parent;
  }

  if(wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=0" )) {
    wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=1" );
  }
}
```

I now realise this does not cope if I am in a grandchild page, in that the uncles and aunties are not displayed, only the parents.

I don't understand how I can adapt this code to display more than 2 levels of menu tree.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function that will output the top level parent along with all of the children of the current page. Helpful menu classes are added to the output. E.g. `page_item_has_children`, `current_page_item`, `current_page_ancestor`, etc.

This solution is [based on one of the examples](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/#comment-391) in the documentation for [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages) and [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99900/2807) here on WPSE, which references the same example.

```
/**
 * Use wp_list_pages() to display parent and all child pages of current page.
 */
function wpse_get_ancestor_tree() {
    // Bail if this is not a page.
    if ( ! is_page() ) {
      return false;
    }

    // Get the current post.
    $post = get_post();

    /**
     * Get array of post ancestor IDs.
     * Note: The direct parent is returned as the first value in the array.
     * The highest level ancestor is returned as the last value in the array.
     * See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors
     */
    $ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );

    // If there are ancestors, get the top level parent.
    // Otherwise use the current post's ID.
    $parent = ( ! empty( $ancestors ) ) ? array_pop( $ancestors ) : $post->ID;

    // Get all pages that are a child of $parent.
    $pages = get_pages( [
                     'child_of' => $parent,
                     ] );

    // Bail if there are no results.
    if ( ! $pages ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Store array of page IDs to include latere on.
    $page_ids = array();
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        $page_ids[] = $page->ID;
    }

    // Add parent page to beginning of $page_ids array.
    array_unshift( $page_ids, $parent );

    // Get the output and return results if they exist.
    $output = wp_list_pages( [
        'include'  => $page_ids,
        'title_li' => false,
        'echo'     => false,
    ] );

    if ( ! $output ) {
        return false;
    } else { 
        return '<ul class="page-menu ancestor-tree">' . PHP_EOL .
                            $output . PHP_EOL .
                        '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
echo wpse_get_ancestor_tree();
```

**Example Page Structure:**

> ```
> Parent Page
>   Child Page 01
>   Child Page 02
>   Child Page 03
>     Grandchild Page
>       Great Grandchild Page
>   Child Page 04
>   Child Page 05
> ```

**Example Output (current page: Great Grandchild Page)**

```
<ul class="page-menu ancestor-tree">
    <li class="page_item page-item-1088 page_item_has_children current_page_ancestor">
        <a href="http://example.com/parent-page/">Parent Page</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="page_item page-item-1090">
                <a href="http://example.com/parent-page/child-page-01/">Child Page 01</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-1092">
                <a href="http://example.com/parent-page/child-page-02/">Child Page 02</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-1094 page_item_has_children current_page_ancestor">
                <a href="http://example.com/parent-page/child-page-03/">Child Page 03</a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li class="page_item page-item-1102 page_item_has_children current_page_ancestor current_page_parent">
                        <a href="http://example.com/parent-page/child-page-03/grandchild-page/">Grandchild Page</a>
                        <ul class="children">
                            <li class="page_item page-item-3066 current_page_item">
                                <a href="http://example.com/parent-page/child-page-03/grandchild-page/great-grandchild-page/">Great Grandchild Page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-1096">
            <a href="http://example.com/parent-page/child-page-04/">Child Page 04</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-1098">
            <a href="http://example.com/parent-page/child-page-05/">Child Page 05</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I had to use `echo $this->wpse_get_ancestor_tree();` too.

Comment: Dave, what order do the child pages get displayed in? I had a child page with a larger page ID display above a child page with a smaller page ID. Thanks.

Comment: @Steve I believe that sorting options are ignored when using the `include` param and that results are ordered by `menu_order`.

Comment: Thanks Dave. How will that work if the nav items are not part of a dedicated WP menu? I don't understand `menu_order` in this context.

Comment: @Steve this code applies to pages, not menu items. Under the *Page Attributes* section, pages have a field labeled *Order* which is stored under the db field `menu_order`.

Comment: @DaveRomsey Great work, how would you display this without the top parent?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're currently only grabbing the parent, and not checking for the top level ancestor.

Try replacing:

```
  if( empty($wp_query->post->post_parent) ) {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
  } else {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->post_parent;
  }
```

with:

```
if ($post->post_parent) {
    $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
    $root=count($ancestors)-1;
    $parent = $ancestors[$root];
} else {
    $parent = $post->ID;
}
```

As per: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/find-id-of-top-most-parent-page/

Comment: Thanks Alex. That actually displayed all pages and their subpages in the menu, rather than all subpages of the top most parent, which is what I'd like to display.

Answer (score 0):

correct code:

```
if( empty($wp_query->post->post_parent) ) {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
} else {
    $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($wp_query->post->ID);
    $parent = $ancestors[count($ancestors)-1];
}
```

it access the top-most page of the current page.

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?